# Variables in handlebars JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am working on a project which has implemented handlebars JS. I have an issue where the following piece of code throws an error. I have got no idea what I am doing wrong here.

```
var split = Split(['#three', '#four', '#five'], {
    minSize: [0, 0, 0]
});
```

The error is **Uncaught ReferenceError: Split is not defined.** I have called the respective plugin JS on top of the code. **require('splitlayout');**

```
    define(function (require) {

    var $ = require('jquery');
    var Thorax = require('thorax');
    var ViewTemplate = require('hbs!../templates/individual-plan.hbs');

    require('splitlayout');

    var GradebookList = Thorax.View.extend({

        template: ViewTemplate,

        events: {
            rendered: function () {

                var split = Split(['#three', '#four', '#five'], {
                        minSize: [0, 0, 0]
                });    
            }
        },

        initialize: function () {
        }
    });

    return GradebookList;
});
```

Comment: If this is what you're referencing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/splitlayout, it appears to be meant for use with react-native - not sure that it'll do anything in this use case

Comment: No, I'm using the following. https://nathancahill.github.io/Split.js/

Comment: You haven't assigned the imported `splitlayout` to a variable. What is `Split`? Just as the runtime says, it has not been defined. Try `var Split = require('splitlayout');`, similar to how your other `require`s are done.